# Remove Gray UITableView Index Bar

Tags: objective-c, scrollbar, hide, uitableview

I am making an application with a UITableView that has a few sections (2), and when I run, the table view has this annoying gray index bar on the side, like the one in the "iPod" application, that has but 2 options in it. My question is, how do I hide the "index bar," because it is an unnecessary waste of space?

Example:
[image]

Code snippets:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [sections count];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return sections;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return 2;
    }
    return 1;
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [sections objectAtIndex:section];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = [content objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row + [[sectionAmounts objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] intValue])];
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    content = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sphere", @"Cylinder", @"Circle", nil];
    sections = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"3d", @"2d", nil];
    sectionAmounts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], nil]; //Second number is objects in first section... odd huh?
    self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [content retain];
    [sections retain];
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

(Mind my odd comments...)

HiGuy

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the section index altogether or just the 'scrollbar'?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That "scroll bar" is your index bar, assuming you're talking about the giant grey thing.

Return nil from sectionIndexTitlesForTableView: and it'll go away.

Comment: I'm going to be away for a while, but when I get back I'll try this. ~Via my iPod touch

Answer (score 15):

I tried this, and it didn't work for me.
so i went through the table view properties, and got this.

```
self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

works like a charm.

*for any one who wants to do this in the future.

Comment: Ehm, doesn't work. Tried this with a basic table view on iOS 5.1

Comment: it should work. tableview is a subclass of uiscrollview, and this property is part of uiscrollview, and its still listed in the class reference. I just tested it out, and it works on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, however had to deal with my header/footer. Essentially I just removed the following methods

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @" "; //@"Top";
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @" "; //@"Bottom";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just use the below code and gray bar will go....

```
    tableViewBrowse.sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sectionIndexBackgroundColor` property of `UITableView` to set the color of index bar to clear color as hiding scroll bar is going to hide the indexes as well.

Add it to your `viewDidLoad:` as following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; //Replace it with your desired color
}
```