# Objective c. How to remove scroll bar from textarea?

Tags: objective-c, text, scroll, field

I need a little help here. 
I made pretty simple app for my iPad with only one text area (by using Text Field object) on background image. I placed some poem in this text field but this poem is more longer than iPas's screen so after running my app I was able to scroll down my poem. 
Now, I want to remove a little grey scroll bar that appears when I scrolling my poem.
Where should I look for an answer? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using a `UITextView` which extends `UIScrollView`, so you can use its `showsVerticalScrollIndicator` property:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    poemView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
}
```

(assuming your text view is an instance variable/outlet of your view controller)

Comment: Thank you for your help but what sould I do if I do not use any instances?

Answer (score 1):

In main storyboard you can find attributes inspector,

there you can disable "Shows vertical indicator"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Remove Gray UITableView Index Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189345/remove-gray-uitableview-scroll-bar)

That "scroll bar" is your index bar.

Return nil from sectionIndexTitlesForTableView: and it'll go away.