# Remove index bar in UITableView when there are few entries

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a similar question to the following question:

[Remove Gray UITableView Index Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189345/remove-gray-uitableview-index-bar)

I'd like to do the same thing, but I would like the scroll bar to show up again when there are enough entries to require scrolling.

Comment: See the `UITableView` property `sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount`.

Comment: @rmaddy That is the answer. You should post it.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy. That was it.  If you submit it as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
if (tableView.contentSize.height < tableView.frame.size.height) {
  self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
}
else {
  self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
}
```

after modifying your tableView data (e.g. after calling reloadData).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410845/how-to-disable-scrolling-in-uitableview-table-when-the-content-fits-on-the-scree) question